# Comparação dando errado

Tags: javascript, string

Vi um exemplo de comparação e fiquei em dúvida do motivo do funcionamento.

Na comparação abaixo, ele retira o texto e `<button>` e compara no `if` para a verificação, se é verdadeiro ou falso, mas ele nunca entra no verdadeiro, mesmo utilizando o `===` para comparar.

Aparentemente, na hora de pegar o valor ele está "convertendo" o `&#709;` e não consegue fazer a comparação.

```js
function trocar(){
  valor = document.getElementById('btnTrocar').innerHTML;
  console.log(valor);
  if(valor == "Imagem &#709;"){
    document.getElementById("btnTrocar").innerHTML = "Imagem  &#706;";
    alert("Texto 1");
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("btnTrocar").innerHTML = "Imagem  &#709;";
    alert("Texto 2");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="trocar()" id="btnTrocar">Imagem &#709;</button>
```

Se existe essa "conversão":

- qual o motivo dela?
- por que ele não trata como um "texto normal"?
- tem alguma forma de pegar esse texto do botão, sem alterar nada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> qual o motivo dela?

Porque essa é uma forma de escrever no código, porque é complicado escrever de outra forma inambiguamente de forma corrente. Mas é só como está no código, no documento não é assim, é o caractere mesmo. Como HTML é uma coisa, como `string` é outra.

> por que ele não trata como um "texto normal"?

Ele trata, você que acha que isso é o texto normal, mas o normal é o caractere representado pelo código `#709`.

> tem alguma forma de pegar esse texto do botão, sem alterar nada?

Claro que não, se está dando erro algo tem que ser alterado. Alterei e deu certo:

```js
function trocar(){
  valor = document.getElementById('btnTrocar').innerHTML;
  console.log(valor);
  if(valor == "Imagem ˅"){
    document.getElementById("btnTrocar").innerHTML = "Imagem  &#706;";
    alert("Texto 1");
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("btnTrocar").innerHTML = "Imagem  &#709;";
    alert("Texto 2");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="trocar()" id="btnTrocar">Imagem &#709;</button>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Comparing.js).

Dentro de uma *string* não corre o risco de confusão e não precisa usar esta forma de códigos especiais. Na verdade para este caso em nenhum lugar precisaria. A não ser para rodar em navegadores que não suportem ler HTML em certas codificações, mas se isto ocorrer provavelmente será o menor dos seus problemas.